# Como enviar una imagen desde java a php

Tags: php, java, post

Como enviar una imagen a una variable $_FILES en un php aparte de otras variables a $_POST, en mi código java puedo enviar solo las variables, pero cuando envío mi arreglo de bytes[] en en que está la imagen convertida a bytes llega vacio al php, y si lo envío como base64 me responde error por ser muy lagra la cadena

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
file = jfc.getSelectedFile();                
int lenght = (int) file.length();
reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
byte[] bytes = new byte[lenght];
reader.read(bytes, 0, lenght);
reader.close();                
String data = "img=hola";
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/xampp/post.php");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());

BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String linea;
while ((linea = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(linea);
}
reader1.close();
```

He intentado enviar solo el array pero de igual manera lo recibe como vacio.

Este es mi php

```
$img=$_POST['img'];

$_response['archivo']="ESTA ES LA IMAGEN: ".$img;
print json_encode($_response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Oh si alguien ya ha logrado hacer algo parecido, de enviar una imagen junto con variables, o si saben alguna alternativa, por favor

Comment: ¿De qué tamaño es el archivo de la imagen?

Comment: Te falta que `Content-Type` sea `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: La imagen que uso para pruebas es de 769KB

Comment: Donde pongo el Content-Type?